# CPU Utilization at 100% with Tomcat 7.0

Tags: tomcat, cpu

We have a WinTel server with 4 CPU's, 8GB of RAM, and a 4GB JVM, running a single browser-based application under a Tomcat 7 service. It will run fine for a day or two, or sometimes a week or two, but eventually the CPU usage will creep up to 100% and then fluctuate between 95% and 100% until the application completely fails to respond. Our only recourse is to then recycle the Tomcat service. We have tweaked the "maxThreads" parameter but this has not resolved the issue. This only occurs on our production server under heavy use...we cannot duplicate this on our non-prod servers because we can't simulate that kind of load. We don't believe it is being caused by the application, but we don't know for sure. We're leaning towards some type of Tomcat configuration issue, but we just don't know where to go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2017-6056/

Answer (score 1):

I found this link, which suggests it's a permSpace issue. At *least that is what I concluded* after reading it.

http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/Tomcat-using-near-100-of-CPU-on-Windows-2008-td4993355.html

I am having a similiar issue, and trying a number of different avenues.

I am also looking into changing the:
-XX:PermSize=64m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=384m

and 
Initial memory Pool 2048 
Maximum Memory pool 2048

that you can gain access to from running  *tomcat7w.exe*

Answer (score 0):

If you have System.gc() in your methods, then just comment that code. Mine working fine now.

Answer (score -4):

could using jetty

1. Download jetty follow version
2. Extract and change port 80 
   Extract to C:\jetty
   open file start.ini int C:\jetty\start.ini change 8080 = 80)
3. Add domain to IP server
   Open etc of OS add (Examle 220.122.15.28 www.carehouse.vn)
4. Config multi webapps

   - create file jetty-web.xml in folder root web (example c:\jetty\webapps\carehouse\WEB-INF)
   - The content jetty-web.xml
   - /
   - /webapps/WebHouse.war
   - 
   - 
   - www.carehouse.vn
     -carehouse.vn 
     -http://carehouse.vn
   - 
5. Run jetty

   - go to cmd and cd to folder root (example: c:\jetty)
   - command: java -jar start.jar